# Integer Expected Exception while training a HMM using Java HMM Library

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read a sequence from a file to train an HMM using Jahmm library. I am getting the following error:

Exception : be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.io.FileFormatException: Integer expected

Following is my vector.seq file

# A simple data file

1; 2; 3;

2; 4; 6;

Following is my code

public class HMMDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Reader reader = new FileReader("vectors.seq");
        List<List<ObservationInteger>> v = ObservationSequencesReader.
          readSequences(new ObservationIntegerReader(), reader);
        reader.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
    }

}
```

}

I am getting an exception "Integer Expected" but in my vector.seq file I have integers only.

I am following the instructions at http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jahmm/example/

Comment: when I tried with another input-file I got the following exception - Exception : be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.io.FileFormatException: Integer higher than maxium value

Answer (score 0):

Never tried

`List<List<ObservationInteger>> v = ObservationSequencesReader.readSequences(new ObservationIntegerReader(), reader);`

However an alternate way is to just read the file, split it on semicolons(after splitting on newline), cast the elements of the array to an Integer, once you have an Integer Array you can then use the ObservationInteger constructor to create an Observation Integer for each element. Round about way but it works.